# React Hook How to pass styles

Tags: reactjs

I wonder if there is a simpler way to pass the default style property (as it is a default property) to a custom component. I hope someone can just tell me how to improve the following code.

Given:

```
const MyIcon= ()=>{
  return <img src={GMNT_N_Black}/>
}
```

The following style property is not being applied.

```
<MyIcon style={{width:"1em",height:"1em"}}/>
```

I'd like to pass the default property `style` to the `img` element in `MyIcon`.

I made it work with the following code:

```
const MyIcon = ({style})=>{
  return <img src={imported_img} style={style}/>
}
```

However, I suspect there should be an easier and cleaner way to pass the style, especially since `img` is the only element inside. Does exist this 'simpler' way or is `{style}` as props the proper way in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
<MyIcon style={{width:"1em",height:"1em"}}/>

    const MyIcon = (props)=>{
      return <img src={imported_img} {...props}/>
    }
```

Whatever property you pass will be applied automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use type `React.CSSProperties` for your styles. Suggestion supported.

```
const MyIcon = ({ style }: { style: React.CSSProperties }) => {
  return <img src={'imported_img'} style={style} />;
};
// Or 
interface MyIconProps {
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}
const MyIcon: React.FC<MyIconProps> = ({ style }) => {
  return <img src={'imported_img'} style={style} />;
};
```

[image]